# Embedding ICC profile using Ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript, color-profile, color-management

I need to embedded the ICC profile while doing converting the PS to PDF using Ghostscript 9.07 in Ubuntu. Could you please give me the exact command to enable the Icc profile?

Icc profile details:

```
ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc for press ps conversion
ECI-RGB.V1.0.icc for web ps conversion
```

I am new to this Ghostscript. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ghostscript you can't embed a specific ICC profile in the output PDF at present, with the exception of PDF/A conversion.

This will change within the next few releases. However, you still won't embed the specific profile, you will just direct Ghostscript to use the profile(s), and then set the ColorConversionStrategy to UseDeviceIndependentColor

Comment: Is this possible embedding the ICC profile in GS 9.08 version?

Comment: 9.08 is not yet released, and is therefore incomplete. Note that you still won't 'embed the profile', you will point the CMS at the profile(s) you want to use and under certain conditions those profiles will end up in the output PDF file. Its not at all clear why you need to 'embed the profile' though. Simply embedding an ICC profile in the PDF file won't have any effect.

Comment: When we embedding the ICC profile for images, we will get the same PDF output view in all machine. if we are not embedding the Icc profile then output view will be differs with the original PDF.

Comment: You cannot simply 'embed a profile' for use with images. You would have to convert the image sample data into the appropriate colour space and define the image as being in that space. You cannot define an image in PostScript as being in an ICCBased space as PostScript does not allow the use of ICC profiles. However, if you simply set ColorConversionStrategy to 'UseDeviceIndependentColor' then all marking operations in the PDF file will be in ICCBased spaces. (continued in next comment)

Comment: Depending how you set the Ghostscript CMS up will determine how the base space solours are converted into ICCBased spaces. You will need 3 profiles, one each for Gray, RGB and CMYK (you have only listed 2). The final output colour will then depend on the consumer and its colour management capabilities. Note that the consumer will convert from the ICCBased space into the relevant device space by using an appropriate ICC colour profile. Whether it looks the same on multiple devices and consumers is up the CMS on the consumer.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation about CMS and ICC profile. We process our graphics right through following the same ICC profile in our systems and finally produce the postscript file through our typesetting system (3B2). As part of requirement for PDF we are required to embed the same ICC profile in our PDF.